# Jenkins: use artifacts from one build in another with directory structure

Tags: .net, jenkins, nant

I am using Jenkins as my build environment for a .NET/C++ Windows product. Jenkins Project A compiles the primary source code into artifacts. Project B builds the installer. The artifacts from project A have a different directory structure than what is required to build the installer in Project B.

I tried using the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)  to copy from Project A to B, but there's a [known limitation](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12379) where I can't specify a different directory structure for the copy.

I'm using a NAnt script in Project B to build the installer. I think the next best thing would be to copy the Project A artifacts to where I need them from the NAnt script. Is it possible to reference a project's artifacts from within a NAnt script so that they can be copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Project B` expects artifacts in a certain structure, then `Project A` should provide them in that structure. As you mentioned, **Archive Artifacts** post-build action does not let you specify alternative location for artifacts, but **it does** preserve their relative structure at the time of archiving.

So, in `Project A`, after the building step (or within it, depending on how you call it), organize the artifacts *before* **Archive Artifacts** is executed.

You can write a simple script, that will take your build artifacts, and copy them under a discrete/unique folder, let's call it `release` folder. Then tell **Archive Artifacts** post-build action to archive only the `release` folder, like `path\to\release\*.*`

It is upto your script to organize the artifacts in the `release` folder in a structure that would be suitable for `Project B`.

BTW, nothing says you cannot move this logic to `Project B`, and have it **Copy Artifacts** from `Project A` as is, and then run a script on `Project B` that will move them into a, let's say, `for_installer` folder and then supply that folder to the packaging process for `Project B`

As for "referencing" the artifacts: The **Copy Artifacts** plugin will copy artifacts of a particular build (by number or label). It defaults to location of archived artifacts (on the "from" part), and to `WORKSPACE` (on the "to" part). In the example above, if your `Project A` organized the artifacts into `release` folder, and your archived that as `path\to\release\*`, then on the **Copy Artifacts** step, set "Artifacts to Copy" as `*`, and leave "Target Directory" blank to be placed directly in Workspace, or specify a directory

Comment: Thank you @Slav, these are good suggestions. I hadn't thought about using additional logic (i.e. using NAnt) either in Project A or B to structure the build artifacts the way I need them, either before or after using **Copy Artifacts**. I was hoping **Copy Artifacts** would have the flexibility to do that for me, but clearly it doesn't.